# KMM with iOS Arm64 Binary Framework (.xcframework) and cinterop

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform, xcframework, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm following the guide here to try and use an iOS framework without CocoaPods in a new KMM project:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-add-dependencies.html#without-cocoapods

I have an existing, working .xcframework that I added to the project under `shared/src`. I added a `MyKit.def` file in `src/nativeInterop/cinterop/` and updated the `build.gradle.kts` file in same shared dir:

MyKit.def looks like

```
language = Objective-C
modules = MyKit
package = MyKit
```

build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()

    val iosTarget: (String, KotlinNativeTarget.() -> Unit) -> KotlinNativeTarget =
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") == true)
            ::iosArm64
        else
            ::iosX64

    iosTarget("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting
        val iosTest by getting
    }
    iosArm64() {
        compilations.getByName("main") {
            val MyKit by cinterops.creating {
                // Path to .def file
                defFile("src/nativeInterop/cinterop/MyKit.def")
                compilerOpts("-framework", "MyKit", "-F/src/MyKit.framework")
            }
        }

        binaries.all {
            // Linker options required to link to the library -- the framework binary is located under src/MyKit.framework/ios-arm64/MyKit.framework/
            linkerOpts("-framework", "MyKit", "-F/src/MyKit.framework/ios-arm64/MyKit.framework/")
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(31)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(26)
        targetSdkVersion(31)
    }
}
```

After adding `import MyKit.*` to my MainActivity I get `unknown reference` errors.

Are iOS binary frameworks supported? They have a `.` separator in the file name so maybe that's an issue. Problem with my `-F` paths?? I'm not clear on whether the path should be all the way to the dir with `Headers` and the binary itself or just to the Framework root. TIA

Comment: Hello, I got to questions to ask. 1. Have you tried with the absolute path to the directory where the framework is? I mean the path you send as `-F` option. 2. Have you performed the `cinteropMyKitIosArm64` task before using the import in your `iosArm64Main` source set?

Comment: Artyom - I have not tried #1 but I will. I don't understand your second question? After adding to or modifying the `build.gradle.kts` I'm running Gradle sync and then running the app from Android Studio on a device, so I would assume the `iosArm64` step has been run. I did not see any instructions to run a cinterop task. Thanks!

Comment: The second question was if you tried to sync and build before checking the code. As you've done it, now I hope the absolute path will help .

Comment: i have the same problem. Did you solved ?

Comment: @Domenico no I was not able to solve it

Comment: Hello again, @mutable2112! If the problem is still relevant to you, I would like to suggest two things to check. 1. Right now its hard to understand whether your framework has `.xcframework` or `.framework` extension. If your cinterop block contains the correct extension, then just forget about this question. 2. What are the results of the `cinteropMyKitIosArm64` in your case? In general, it should create a `.klib` file located at `$projectbuild/classes/kotlin/native/main/cinterop/.` if its empty that mean the `cinterop` tool did not found the appropriate headers to generate bindings.

Comment: If its true, I would recommend checking if the framework structure is not too different from the standard `MyKit.framework/module.modulemap` and `MyKit.framework/Headers/MyKitHeadersAsNamedInTheModulemap`.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I created local `xcframework` using `xcode` and added dependency to `Android studio` and was able to create `.klib` library in `$projectbuild/classes/kotlin/native/main/cinterop/`. But couldn't import my library either in `xcode` nor in `iosMain` source  set.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have the default KMM project structure with also the framework and the def file as follows:

```
- androidApp
- iosApp
  - MyFramework.framework
- shared
  - src
    - nativeInterop
      - cinterop
        - MyFramework.def
```

This is what you need to add in your `build.gradle` file:

```kotlin
    val myFrameworkDefFilePath = "src/nativeInterop/cinterop/MyFramework.def"
    val myFrameworkCompilerLinkerOpts = listOf("-framework", "MyFramework", "-F${projectDir}/../iosApp/")
    iosArm64 {
        compilations.getByName("main") {
            val MyFramework by cinterops.creating {
                // Path to .def file
                defFile(myFrameworkDefFilePath)

                compilerOpts(myFrameworkCompilerLinkerOpts)
            }
        }

        binaries.all {
            // Tell the linker where the framework is located.
            linkerOpts(myFrameworkCompilerLinkerOpts)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, as stated [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2314), relative paths don't work correctly as compiler arguments, so what you can do is use `projectDir` value and from that point to where your framework is located.

Note: you need to point to the parent folder of where the framework is (in the example, I'm pointing to `iosApp/`, which is the parent of `MyFramework.framework`).

Another note: if you have an `.framework`, afaik, you need to replicate this code for `iosX64`, `iosArm64`, `iosSimulatorArm64`, whatever, to make the imports work correctly in `iosMain`.
If you have an `.xcframework` the path needs to point to the correct variant inside the `.xcframework`, e.g. `ios-arm64_armv7`, `ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator`, whatever.